# How can I make iCarousel work with the headerView in a UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, icarousel

I am testing how to use TableViewController in iOS programming.
I succeeded in populating the controller's table view and even add a header view to it, now I want to make it more interesting by creating a scrollable image gallery on the top of the view.

And I found this iCarousel component.

My thought is to integrate iCarousel into HeaderView but I failed to make it work.

Am I on the right track or I overcomplicate things? Maybe I can try UIScrollView? I haven't used it before though.

Thanks all,
John

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out how to do it. Actually the iCarousel lib might be a little overkill in my case. I just need to have a set of images shown in turn at the top of my table view.

Here is what I did:

1. create a image view from interface builder;
2. Set its File owner to be my tableview controller;
3. Link the tableview controller's headView to the image view;
4. load the imageView's xib file inside the method headView;
5. Add code below to the viewDidLoad method:

   UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)self.headerView;

   ```
   imageView.animationImages = @[
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"image_1"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"image_2"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"image_3"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"image_4"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"image_5"]
                                 ];


   imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
   imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
   imageView.animationDuration = 10;
   [imageView startAnimating];

   imageView.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
   imageView.accessibilityLabel = NSLocalizedString(@"Animated", nil);
   ```

   [self.tableView setTableHeaderView:imageView];